# Creating an array of objects without a default constructor

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-arrays

I have read in many places that in c++ you cannot use the new[] operator to create an array of objects that do not have a default constructor. I also understand that I can use vectors to easily achieve this.

However, I tried the following code which did seem to give me the ability to use the new[] operator for an array of objects without a default constructor:

```
struct mystuff{
    int data1, data2;

    mystuff(int a){
        data1 = a;
        data2 = 10;
    }
    mystuff(int a, int g){
        data1 = a;
        data2 = g;
    }
};

int main(){
    mystuff *b = static_cast<mystuff*> (::operator new (sizeof(mystuff[5]))); //allocate memory
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        std::cout << &b[i] << std::endl; //addresses of allocated memory
    }
    new (b + 1)mystuff(5); //initialize one of the values in the array with non default constructor
    new (b + 3)mystuff(10, 15); //initialize one of the values in the array with non default constructor
    std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        std::cout << &b[i] << std::endl; //addresses of allocated memory after constructor
    }

    std::cout << "Values of constructed objects" << std::endl;
    std::cout << b[1].data1 << "," << b[1].data2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << b[3].data1 << "," << b[3].data2 << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    delete[] b;
    return 0;
}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can tell me whether this is a legitimate thing to do or if what is shown is very wrong and dangerous for some reason that I do not realize  (i.e. I somehow created a memory leak in this specific example).

Thanks so much

Comment: Congratulations, you have reinvented `std::vector`.

Comment: This is basically what `std::vector` does -- but you should only do this if you know what you are doing, and you should definitely implement these dangerous parts inside of a class so you only have to get it right *one time*. Or... just use `std::vector` since they already did that for you. For example, your `delete[]` is going to destruct even the uninitialized objects, which is harmless in this case but may be disastrous if you have a non-POD class. You would need to explicitly call the destructor of only the objects you placement-new'd, and then use `::operator delete` on the array.

Comment: `delete[] b;` invokes Undefined Behaviour. The pointer *must* be from an array-new-expression. I.e. you'll have to call the destructors manually and call `::operator delete`.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide initializers for dynamic arrays, and you can also populate vectors:

```
mystuff * b = new mystuff[3] { mystuff(1), mystuff(2, 3), mystuff(4) };
// *b is leaked
```

```
std::vector<mystuff> const c { mystuff(1), mystuff(2, 3), mystuff(4) };
```

Comment: This is new in C++11, which explains why many sources say it's impossible. Note however that the first one doesn't work with a run-time array size.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is essentially the same as `std::vector` is doing in its insides.

As it is, your code is not legitimate. First, for objects created with placement `new` you must call destructors manually:

```
b[1].~mystuff();
b[3].~mystuff();
```

And second, `delete[] b` is illegal because it's called for memory not allocated with `new[]`, so you have undefined behavior. So you should replace it with `::operator delete(b);` or  `::operator delete(b, sizeof(mystuff[5])));`.